Snowflake SQL stored procedure not working
I am trying to create a SQL stored procedure in Snowflake (Snowsight), but it is throwing run-time error. Not able to identify what the issue is.
I am getting thius error :

invalid identifier 'C_KEY_REC.KEY_NM'

Can anyone please help? I am new to this and will have to use the SQL stored procedure. Did not get any resolutions from around Google.
Below is a mocked-up version of what I have :
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE KEY_TBL
(
     key_nm         VARCHAR
    ,key_val        VARCHAR
    ,active_yn      VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO KEY_TBL(key_nm, key_val, active_yn )
VALUES
     ('KEY_NAME_1','KEY_VAL_1', 'Y')
    ,('KEY_NAME_2','KEY_VAL_2', 'Y')
;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE LOOP_CHK
(
     key_nm         VARCHAR
    ,key_val        VARCHAR
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_LOOP_TEST()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
    cur_key    CURSOR FOR SELECT key_nm, key_val FROM KEY_TBL WHERE active_yn = 'Y' ORDER BY key_nm;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur_key;
    FOR c_key_rec IN cur_key
    DO
        INSERT INTO LOOP_CHK(key_nm, key_val)
        VALUES(c_key_rec.key_nm, c_key_rec.key_val);
    END FOR;
    RETURN '1';
END;
;

CALL SP_LOOP_TEST();

I tried both with and without the OPEN statement. Checked the Snowflake docs and also this site and others in google. But could not resolve.

you need to use  dynamic SQL (execute immediate) when using cursor
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_LOOP_TEST()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
    cur_key cursor for  SELECT key_nm, key_val 
    FROM KEY_TBL WHERE active_yn = 'Y' ORDER BY key_nm;
v_insert_stmt varchar2;
    --cur_main cursor for select sis_table,census_table, sis_column_list, process_flag 
     --       from CENSUS_HISTORY.CENSUS_SIS_MAPPING   WHERE process_flag = 'Y';
BEGIN
   -- OPEN cur_key;
   FOR c_key_rec IN cur_key do

   v_insert_stmt := ' INSERT INTO LOOP_CHK(key_nm, key_val) ' ||
        ' VALUES(' || '\'' || c_key_rec.key_nm || '\'' || ', 
                    ' || '\''||  c_key_rec.key_val || '\'' || ' )';
    execute immediate v_insert_stmt;    
    END FOR;
    RETURN '1';
END;


Thanks @Himanshu. Do I have to do the dynamic query approach for SELECT statements instead of INSERT ?

@JayantaPaul No dynamic will be only when you use the data that you are getting from cursor.
